# trying to extract file from corrupted zip

Tags: zip, unzip, 7zip, php-ziparchive, unexpectendoffile

after a few attempts at the file with zip -F and zip -FF and 7zip and some other repairing tools,
when running `zipdetails` it says : `Unexpecded END at offset 00122462, value D40D148C`.
can I somehow use a hex editor to fix it? what does it mean "Unexpecded END at offset .., value ..." ?
thanks!

Comment: The "unexpected END" message means that zipdetails couldn't read the zip file. Did it print anything apart from that message? Also, did "zip -F" and the other tools recover any of the zip file?

Comment: it printed "000000 PREFIX DATA". 
zip -FF recovered an empty file :(

Comment: If "zip -FF" cannot salvage anything from the file then you are out of luck.The zip file contains no useful data.